# Representation of floating point (14bit)

Tags: floating-point, representation

sign 1 bit, exponent 5 bit, fraction 8bit (I think it's IEEE 754 Standard)

What is the largest decimal value and smallest value that can be represented using above 14 bit float?

isn't 0 11111 11111111 and 1 11111 11111111? if not what would be the answer?

can someone explain in detail?

And what should be smallest value but bigger than zero.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer on the information given: just telling us the number of exponent bits and number of fraction bits does not determine the floating-point format. Is this an IEEE 754-like format? Is it even a binary format? (It could be hexadecimal, for example. I'm assuming not, but you don't say.) Is the significand always normalised? Is the significand considered to be in the form `1.fraction` or `0.fraction`, or something else? What's the exponent bias? Is there a reserved exponent for infinities and nans? Is there a reserved exponent for subnormals and zeros?

Comment: What do you mean by "smallest largest decimal"? How is your representation defined? Similar to IEEE754 (with normals/denormals, infinities/NaNs, exponent-bias, ...)?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't write down the problem properly. I looked at the problem again. The format follows the IEEE754, and the exponent bias is 15... about significand .. I think it follow format of 1.fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the IEEE-754 pattern for binary formats, with 1 sign bit, a 5-bit exponent biased by 15, and 8 bits for the primary significand field:

- The smallest value that can be represented is −∞, with bits 1 11111 00000000.
- The smallest finite value that can be represented is −2<sup>30−15</sup>•1.11111111<sub>2</sub> = −2<sup>15</sup>•(2−2<sup>−8</sup>) = −(2<sup>16</sup>−2<sup>7</sup> = −(65536-128) = −65,408, with bits 1 11110 11111111.
- The smallest positive value that can be represented is +2<sup>1−15</sup>•0.00000001<sub>2</sub> = +2<sup>−14</sup>•2<sup>−8</sup> = +2<sup>−22</sup>, with bits 0 00000 00000001.
- The largest finite value that can be represented is the negation of the smallest finite value, shown above: +2<sup>30−15</sup>•1.11111111<sub>2</sub> = +2<sup>15</sup>•(2−2<sup>−8</sup>) = +(2<sup>16</sup>−2<sup>7</sup> = +(65536-128) = +65,408, with bits 0 11110 11111111.
- The largest value that can be represented is +∞, with bits 0 11111 00000000.

> What is the largest decimal value…

Binary floating-point numbers represent a set of real numbers. They do so using binary digits, effectively being binary numerals. They do not represent decimal values *per se* and do not have decimal digits. Their values can be shown using decimal numerals, as shown above.